# Naked domain not working on VirtualHost for EC2

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, mod-rewrite

I am using AWS EC2 and I am redirecting example.com domain to a directory in EC2 with the following virtual host:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com *.example.com
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    # WITH 'www.'
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.(.*) [nocase]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [redirect=permanent,nocase,last]
  </IfModule>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/Example
</VirtualHost>
```

Now it when I go to www.example.com it is working correctly. However, using the naked domain http://example.com I get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
GET http://peep.ie/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

This is the DNS configuration:

```
A   *.example.com.  xxx.yyy.zzz.ttt 3600    Manual   Active  Yes
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*.example.com` covers all subdomains of `example.com`, but not `example.com` itself. You need a second DNS record.